# Сделать предпросмотр изображений или силуэт

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

Необходимо решить проблему отображения картинок которые еще не загрузились.
Реализую одно приложение с использование `CardView`. Каждый элемент это некий layout с `ImageView`.

Хотелось бы видеть силуэт картинки или хотя бы белый квадрат равный размеру картинки, размер картинки предварительно известен, так же надо что бы картинка была во всю ширину одной карточки (Элемента), а высота подбиралась сама пропорционально.

Как можно реализовать данную вещь, может есть уже готовые решения, или может я что то не так делаю или не понимаю.

Comment: готовое решение - [библиотека Pacasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) умеет работать с [placeholder](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#placeholder-int-) (изображение-заглушка) и еще много [чего полезного](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/picasso.php)

Comment: @pavlofff а как указать плейсхолдуру высоту и ширину и, что бы он адаптировался по ширине?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для загрузки изображений можно использовать [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) или [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Лично я сторонник Glide так как с паматью он управляется лучше и качество картинок тоже лучше. Чтобы отображать что то до того как картинка загрузиться советую поставить либо белую картинку либи любую другую на фон ImageView. Когда фото загрузиться то статическая картинка замениться загруженной.

Comment: Спасибо посмотрю эти варианты, в общем я думаю Picasso буду юзать.